# Can I automatically link Jira issue with confluence page

Tags: groovy, jira, confluence

I am trying to create a process with Jira and confluence, using Scriptrunner Cloud.
I am trying to do the following :
I want to create a confluence page automatically with posfunction scriptrunner on Jira issue creation, and want to link this page and issue automatically too.

I already automatized creation with some code, but this code does not link page and issues automatically.
I am using following code :

```
def spaceKey = 'LTSE'

def result = get("/rest/api/3/issue/${issueKey}")
    .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .asObject(Map)
if (result.status != 200) {
    return "Error retrieving issue ${result}"
}

def title = "${result.body.key} - ${result.body.fields.summary}"
def rootContent = "<h2>Description</h2><p>${result.body.fields.description}</p>"
def parent = createConfluencePage(title, spaceKey, rootContent, null)

result.body.fields.subtasks.forEach { subtask ->
    def subtaskResult = get("/rest/api/3/issue/${subtask.id}")
        .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .asObject(Map)
    if (subtaskResult.status != 200) {
        logger.error("Error retrieving issue ${subtaskResult}")
    }

    def subtitle = "${subtask.key} - ${subtask.fields.summary}"
    def pageContent = "<h2>Description</h2><p>${subtaskResult.body.fields.description}</p>"

    createConfluencePage(subtitle, spaceKey, pageContent, parent)
}

String createConfluencePage(String pageTitle, String spaceKey, String pageContent, String parentPage) {
    def params = [
        type : "page",
        title: pageTitle,
        space: [
            key: spaceKey
        ],
        body : [
            storage: [
                value         : pageContent.toString(),
                representation: "storage"
            ]
        ]

    ]
    if (parentPage != null) {
        params["ancestors"] = [parentPage].collect { [id: parentPage.toString()] }
    }

    def pageResult = post('/wiki/rest/api/content')
        .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .body(params)
        .asObject(Map).body

    if (pageResult.statusCode) {
        logger.error("Failed to create a new page. Confluence responded with error code: {}", pageResult.statusCode)
    } else {
        logger.info("Successfully created a new space with id: {}", pageResult)
    }
    pageResult.id
}

parent
```

Is there anything I can do, to automatize linking? 
please have in mind that I use Cloud Jira and confluence

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to add content to the Confluence page using Scriptrunner? If so, just add the link of the JIRA issue to the Confluence page. This will automatically be converted to a JIRA issue macro on the page and will create a link with the JIRA issue itself. See:
https://www.atlassian.com/blog/confluence/link-jira-issues-to-confluence-pages-automatically

This only works if you have created application links between JIRA and Confluence:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/using-applinks-to-link-to-other-applications-779295829.html